# Two-way encryption + look-up?

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption, hash

If I don't want to store user emails in plain text in the database, but need them for running look-ups, is there a way to both encrypt (two-way so the content can be retrieved) and easily look up the value?

*EDIT* Would storing two columns, one encrypted for display and one hashed for lookup work?

Comment: By "lookup" do you mean decrypt and show the password in plain text?

Comment: Does "user email" mean "user e-mail address" or "user e-mail message"?

Comment: I want to add a degree of security where if the database was compromised, it would still be encrypted and require them to also access the key.

Comment: Why take so much caution with you user's email addresses? They probably gave it to facebook already, who's shamelessly sharing it with whoever wants it ;)

Comment: @Romain I know you're only joking, but I think joking about security is a bad idea. I wish more people took my personal information seriously -- even my email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL has [`aes_encrypt()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) and [`aes_decrypt()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt) for this sort of thing, but then you're still passing the encryption key in-the-clear, which means you might as well just be passing around the email addresses in-the-clear.

The basic method would be something like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable
WHERE encrypted_email = AES_ENCRYPT('someone@example.com', 'crypt key here');
```

but again, you'd not be gaining any security since you're sending the key each time.

Comment: How would you go about performing the encryption/decryption without sending the encryption key in-the-clear?

Comment: @cable729 You can't. Or you load all your addresses from the DB,d decrypt them in application code, then figure out the encrypted value that matches the one you're looking for.

Comment: @Marc B Also, how do you get your "aes_encrypt()" to display in blue? :)

Comment: @cable729 He inserted links to the documentation, links show up in blue.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're encrypting your data. Are you doing the encryption in code and then inserting the encrypted values? If so, then you can look up values just by looking up the encrypted value instead of the plaintext value.

Pseudocode:

```
string encryptedEmail = Encrypt("test@test.com", myEncryptionKey);
....
string sInsert = "INSERT INTO table (email) VALUES ('" + encryptedEmail + "')";
...
string sSelect = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = '" + encryptedEmail + "'";
```

Now you're only ever passing encrypted information over the wire, the key never goes anywhere.